# Storekit 2 is not available on this device

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap, storekit2

I've implemented a subscription process for users using EXPO IAP, but to check if the user has a current subscription for IOS, I'm using react-native-IAP and implementing storekit 2 using this package, but I am getting the following error when trying to use one of the functions:

```
import {initConnection,IapIosSk2, setup} from "react-native-iap"

setup({storekitMode:'STOREKIT2_MODE'})
await initConnection()
const status = IapIosSk2.subscriptionStatus('sku')
```

which returns this error:

```
 WARN  Storekit 2 is not available on this device
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: IAP_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

I'm running the app through expo dev simulator on my iphone with the latest IOS 16 version.  Storekit 2 only works with IOS 15+, which my phone is capable of.  **Do I need to specify somewhere in my app.json that IOS must be 15 or greater?**

Comment: Looking at the logic that produces that warning, you are not running on a device with iOS 15+.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am running it with a expo simulator that puts the app on my iphone, which as stated in the question, is running the latest IOS 16

Comment: Maybe it is something about that simulator. I don't know. The code that produces that warning is pretty simple. It checks the version of iOS. You should be able to run the app under the Xcode debugger and set a breakpoint in the native code, but I don't use expo so I don't know exactly how.  Can you get expo to actually build and install the native app on your phone?

Comment: @Paulw11 I fixed it with this: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/

Comment: @Paulw11 How did you fix it using `expo-build-properties`? Which is the thing you added to `app.json` that fixed the error when you run your app using Expo Go?

Comment: I didn't fix it. Michael did. I imagine he set the deployment target to iOS 15

Comment: @AthenaWisdom Yes, as Paul said, I added the deployment target to IOS 15.